# How can I prevent automerge on specific files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, build, merge

We are currently running multiple branches within TFS 2013:

```
Development
Release
Trunk
etc.
```

Each branch has an automated test build.  The purpose of these builds is to publish the latest code (and database changes) for each branch to our test server for manual testing.  We maintain a separate IIS application for each branch so that different versions can be tested simultaneously.

Each branch has unique .csproj, .xml profile and web.config settings which control which application and database each branch deploys to, which works great.

However when we merge from one branch to another, auto-merge replaces these branch specific settings causing us to deploy our test builds to the wrong URL and database.

I am aware that auto-merge can be completely disabled in Visual Studio settings but is there a way we can continue to use auto-merge except for specific files?

Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known problem with any code promotion model. I would suggest that you move instead to a binary promotion model.

http://nakedalm.com/building-release-pipeline-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

With a binary promotion model you build the bits once with replaceable parameters and create or use a tool that orchestrates the release and feeds it with the correct variables for each environment.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

I recently built out an end to end scenario using VSO. You can see in the post the passing of the values for each environment.

The software industry is moving towards continuous delivery and continuous integration. Neither of which is possible in a code promotion model.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable auto conflict resolving during merge, but in this case you have to resolve these conflict manually (ignore)

*Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated*

or you could use tf.exe for merge:

```
tf.exe merge /discard CS
```

use a changeset which will be always discard from merge.